# Leitura de dados de um arquivo com Java

Tags: java, txt, scanner

Boa noite, tenho um arquivo de texto como o da imagem

[image: Print do arquivo de texto]

Eu preciso ler esse arquivo e pegar os dados e guardar em um array de objeto.
Por exemplo, eu tenho um objeto SALA, esse objeto tem os seguintes atributos:

numero = room ||
norte = north ||
sul = south   ||
lest = east   || 
oeste = west  ||
cima = up     ||
baixo = down  ||

Na primeira linha por exemplo deveria ficar assim

Sala sala = new Sala (1, null, 6, 2, null, null, null);

Eu consegui ler o arquivo com o scanner, tranquilo, só que como as informações do arquivo não seguem um padrão, não sei como capturar os dados corretos....

alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo pra você usando **split** para quebrar os espaços das linhas e salvar num array e um **switch** para verificar se o nome em cada um dos pedaços equivale a um dos valores do switch e, se casar, guarda na variável sala o valor do próximo pedaço, que é o valor correspondente. Vendo o código abaixo você entenderá melhor.

Criei um projeto Java simples com um pacote chamado *lerarquivotxt* e 3 arquivos dentro.

Para começar criamos um objeto Sala que servirá para guardar os valores.

**Sala.java**

```
package lerarquivotxt;

public class Sala
{
    int numero,norte,sul,leste,oeste,cima,baixo;

    // Construtor de sala vazia
    public Sala Sala()
    {
        return this;
    }

    // Construtor com parâmetros para preenchimento
    public Sala Sala(int room, int north, int south, int east, int west, int up, int down)
    {
        numero = room;
        norte = north;
        sul = south;
        leste = east;
        oeste = west;
        cima = up;
        baixo = down;

        return this;
    }

}
```

O segundo construtor dessa classe Sala não será usado, mas você pode usá-lo para testar criando os objetos passando os parâmetros manualmente se quiser.

O próximo arquivo é um executável que lerá o arquivo e irá criar objetos do tipo sala e guardá-los na lista.

**LerArquivoTxt.java**

```
package lerarquivotxt;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LerArquivoTxt
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File f = new File("");

        String caminhoarquivo = "src" + f.separatorChar + "lerarquivotxt" + f.separatorChar + "arquivotexto.txt";

        //System.out.println("Caminho absoluto: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + f.separatorChar + caminhoarquivo);

        // Lista que armazenará as salas
        ArrayList<Sala> salas = new ArrayList<>();

        Sala sala;

        // Lê o arquivo que está no mesmo pacote
        try
        {
            FileReader arq = new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath() + f.separatorChar + caminhoarquivo);

            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

            String linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê a primeira linha
            sala = linha2sala(linha); 
            salas.add(sala);            

            // a variável linha será igual a null ao chegar no fim do arquivo
            while (linha != null)
            {
                linha = lerArq.readLine(); // lê da segunda até a última linha


                if(linha!=null)
                {
                    sala = linha2sala(linha); // converte linha em uma sala
                    salas.add(sala); // salva a sala na lista  
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
              System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n",
                e.getMessage());
        }     


        // for each que exibe a lista de salas para demonstrar que está tudo correto
        for(Sala minhasala : salas)
        {
            System.out.println( 
                                "Sala: "    + minhasala.numero   + " \t " +
                                "Norte: "   + minhasala.norte    + " \t " +
                                "Sul: "     + minhasala.sul      + " \t " +
                                "Leste: "   + minhasala.leste    + " \t " +
                                "Oeste: "   + minhasala.oeste    + " \t " +
                                "Cima: "    + minhasala.cima     + " \t " +
                                "Baixo: "   + minhasala.baixo    
                               );
        }
    }




    static Sala linha2sala(String linha)
    {
        Sala sala = new Sala();

        // quebra os espaços e guarda num array para poder percorrer com um for

        String[] pedacos = linha.split(" ");

        int qtd = pedacos.length;

        // percorre os pedacos q formavam a linha, setando valores da sala
        for(int i=0; i<qtd; i++)
        {
            // se o pedaço é um nome, o próximo pedaço é o valor correspondente 
            switch(pedacos[i])
            {
                case "room":
                    sala.numero=Integer.parseInt(pedacos[i+1]);
                    break;

                case "north":
                    sala.norte=Integer.parseInt(pedacos[i+1]);
                    break;

                case "south":
                    sala.sul=Integer.parseInt(pedacos[i+1]);
                    break;

                case "east":
                    sala.leste=Integer.parseInt(pedacos[i+1]);
                    break;

                case "west":
                    sala.oeste=Integer.parseInt(pedacos[i+1]);
                    break;

                case "up":
                    sala.cima=Integer.parseInt(pedacos[i+1]);
                    break;

                case "down":
                    sala.baixo=Integer.parseInt(pedacos[i+1]);
                    break;     
            }
        }


        return sala;
    }

}
```

Nota: Apenas pondo o arquivo na mesma pasta e passando o nome dele ele não estava sendo achado, então usei um getAbsolutePath a partir de um arquivo vazio e montei o caminho. Não sei se essa é a melhor maneira de lidar com os caminhos de arquivos, mas resolveu sem problema. No entanto aceito opiniões de como isso pode ser melhorado.

O terceiro arquivo é a lista que você passou. Peguei sua imagem e converti em texto usando um site de OCR Online, em seguida incluí \r\n para quebrar cada linha.

**arquivotexto.txt**

```
room 1 south 6 east 2 
room 2 east 3 west 1 
room 3 south 8 east 4 west 2 
room 4 south 7 east 5 west 3 
room 5 south 9 west 4 
room 6 north 1 south 10 west 0 
room 7 north 4 east 9 west 8 
room 8 north 3 south 12 east 7 up 24 
room 9 north 5 south 13 west 7 
room 10 north 6 south 14 east 11 
room 11 east 12 west 10 up 22 
room 12 north 8 south 15 west 11 
room 13 north 9 south 17 
room 14 north 10 south 0 
room 15 north 12 east 16 west 0 up 25 
room 16 east 17 west 15 
room 17 north 13 south 0 west 16 
room 18 north 24 south 25 east 19 west 22 up 28 
room 19 south 26 east 20 west 18 
room 20 east 19 
room 21 east 22 
room 22 north 23 east 18 west 21 down 11 
room 23 south 22 east 24 
room 24 south 18 west 23 down 8 
room 25 north 18 east 26 down 15 
room 26 north 19 west 25 
room 27 east 28 
room 28 north 30 south 31 east 29 west 27 down 18 
room 29 west 28 
room 30 south 28 
room 31 north 28
```

Se essa resposta tiver lhe ajudado a resolver o seu problema, dê uma moral aceitando-a como resposta e clicando no triângulo pra cima para dar também um +1.

Comment: Isso mesmo, estou terminando de fazer usando essa lógica, só estou lendo os arquivos com o scanner

Answer (score 1):

Fala, Rafael.

Você já tem o texto guardado em alguma estrutura de dados da Java? Se tem um stream com o conteúdo pode dar uma pesquisada em como transformar em String. Se tem uma String com o conteúdo pode dar uma pesquisa em como transformar isso numa lista de strings com um item pra cada linha.

Tendo as linhas tu pode usar [regex](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html), com as funções de busca de cada propriedade.

Pode notar que existe um padrão:

```
[1]comodo [2]número-do-comodo[n]plano-cartesiano...
```

Onde 1 vai ser o cômodo, 2 o número do cômodo e **n** vair ser tudo o que vier depois, nesse caso um grupo formado por `coordenada posição`.

Aí é só guardar no teu objeto enquanto iterar pela lista.

Comment: valeu, fiz conforme o antonio disse